# Проверить наличие записи в любой из строк столбца MySQL [PHP]

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Как правильно реализовать код без костылей или хотябы с минимальными?

Этапы:

1. Разбираем GET запрос по переменным
2. Пробуем подключиться к базе данных
3. Берем переменную $hwid(У каждого ПК она уникальная)
4. Выбираем базу для записи

Если переменная $hwid уже есть в ЛЮБОЙ из строк в столбце 'hwid' , то добавляем ее в таблицу 1 сроком на 2 минуты
Если переменная $hwid не найдена в ЛЮБОЙ из строк в столбце 'hwid', то добавляем ее в таблицу 2

```
<?PHP
$time = $_GET['time'];
$cpu = $_GET['cpu'];
$gpu = $_GET['gpu'];
$user = $_GET['user'];
$win = $_GET['win'];
$hwid = $_GET['hwid'];

$servername = "localhost";
$database = "db_1";
$username = "login";
$password = "pass";

// Устанавливаем соединение
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);
mysqli_set_charset($conn, 'utf8');

// Проверяем соединение

if (!$conn) 
{
die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
else
{
echo "Connectedsuccessfully";
}

//условие записи

if() //если строки $hwid нет НИ В ОДНОМ из строк столбца 'hwid'
{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (time, cpu, gpu, username, winversion, hwid) VALUES ('$time', '$cpu', '$gpu', '$user', '$win' ,'$hwid')";
    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) 
    {
      echo "New recordcreatedsuccessfully";
    }
    else
    {
      echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
    }
    mysqli_close($conn);*/
}
else
{
    //Добавить в другую базу данных запись сроком на 2 минуты.
}
```

?>

Comment: тебе весь учебник php пересказать или ты не можешь if условие пропсиать?))

Comment: @Jean-Claude не понимаю как прописать поиск и как ограничить время пребывания записи в базе

Comment: SELECT значит сначала надо сделать, чтобы проверить существует ли запись в бд, если не сущесвтует - INSERT. Вообще добавлять на 2 минуты в бд - это бред, для этого существуют куки, сессии. Но можно кроном подчищать записи, время жизни которых истекло.

Comment: @Jean-Claude в этом то и дело, что надо по времени добавлять, ибо пытаюсь делать скрипт, показывающий онлайн программа или нет. Программа раз в 2 минуты отправляет GET запрос на скрипт и она должна его обработать

Comment: добавляй просто временную метку, а потом сравнивай её с текущим временем, больше 2 минут = считай записи нет.

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = "SELECT 6 FROM users WHERE hwid LIKE '%".$hwid."%'";
$s = mysqli_query($conn, $result);
if ($s->num_rows > 0)
{
    echo "1"; // Если значение существует
}
else
{
    echo "2"; //Если значения нет
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]